# Converting several java variables to a single object using object serialization

Tags: java, object, parameters, serializable

The following code is used to get several parameters from a java method.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Example implements Serializable{
 void getValues(String m,int x, int y){
}
}
```

How can I get the 3 paramaters m,x and y into a single object using object serialization?

Comment: I haven't understood you problem. Is this what you want? `class Bla { private String m; private int x, private int y; // constructor(s), setters and getters... }` then `void getValues(Bla bla)...`

Comment: wrap m,x and y into a single object variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map`.

Create a new class holding the 3 parameters for the key

```
public class ThreeParameters implements Serializable {
    private final String m;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    ...
    // Remember to override equals and hashcode
}
```

Create a `Map` with `ThreeParameters` as keys.

```
public Map<ThreeParameters, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

.... // Add elements with put 

// map is a Serializable object as required
```

Comment: thanx if I want to deserialize the object into the 3 iniial variables then how can I do it?

Comment: add getters to the ThreeParameters class and get them as you need.